# my project not found classes there were generated by android-annotations

Tags: android, eclipse, annotations

Ive already configured my project how described at [Project wiki page](https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations/wiki/Eclipse-Project-Configuration), but when I add `@EActivity` on my activities and updates `AndroidManifest.xml`.

The Eclipse still not see this last update at AndroidManifest.xml and suggest me change activity name with underscore suffix. but i just do this!

Well, when I do CLEAN in my project and try to run on emulator my project crashes (it dont see the class files generated by AndroidAnnotations)

```
@EActivity(R.layout.activity_info)
public class InfoActivity extends Activity { ... }

<activity android:name="com.mypackage.xxx.InfoActivity_"/>
```

With this, i can see the class generated correctly by android-annotations.. but my project dont see.

I try to change default conf to `Project Preferences > Java Compiler > Annotation Processing > Generated source directory` to gen folder and works!

But I believe this folder dont follow Android standards .. I dont know ..

Someone can help me?